# Bigquery SQL - conditional string agg

Tags: string, google-bigquery

I have the following table -
Columns -
row number (name - colA),
integer - a random number (colB) might be any value.
id - short string, might be null (colC).

```
1  2  'a'
2  4  'b'
3  6  
4  1  'c'
```

Expected result -

```
1  2  'a'  
2  4  'b'  'a'
3  6       'a, b'
4  1  'c'  NULL
5  3  'd'  'b'
```

The process of generating the last column -
For each row - Taking colB from that row ("examined row") and test each row above it (after ordering by colA) ("tested row").
examined_row.colB >= tested_row.colB. If so - we take ColC.

After checking all the tested rows - we string_agg(colC)

Does anyone has idea how to do it in SQL without massive inner join ?

Thought about string agg, however, for the first part (the condition) - I have no idea how to handle the value from the examined row and compare it to the tested row, since analytical function can't be into string_agg().
Also sub query might not help as I see it.
The only solution I thought is inner join, but it not effecient.
Even if you have solution with array_agg is also better.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select colA, colB, colC,
  (
    select string_agg(colC, ', ')
    from t.candidates
    where t.colB > colB
    order by colA
  ) as colD
from (
  select *, array_agg(struct(colB, colC)) over win as candidates
  from `project.dataset.table`
  window win as (order by colA rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding )
) t
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]